# Best practice for setState in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Which is the better way to setState in reactJs.

case 1: to store separate state variables

```
this.setState({
  value1: 'value1',
  value2: 'value2',
  ....
  valueN:'valueN'
})
```

case 2: to store in state object

```
this.setState({
  values: {
    ...values,
    [key]: value
  }
});
```

Is there any performance issue in both cases?

Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on the usage of the values stored inside "store".

Comment: I would avoid nested states as much as possible but again depends on the use case.

Comment: don't worry about performance until performance becomes a problem. If it's important to "know", then you should test it yourself and decide through your own, empirical evidence and observation. You should not base it on our opinions.

Comment: Keep your state shape as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use. For example, if the data belongs to only one thing or one concept keep it in a single variable inside the state and if they belong to different things do the reverse. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

in your case 1, you are only assigning values, and in the case 2, you are using a predefined value adding a a new element.

Generally you can mix key and values, and  make operations inside setStates

```
this.setState({
  value1: {
    ...values,
    [key]: value
  },
  value2: 'value2',
  value3:  [...otherArrayValues, newValue]
  loading: false,
  id: '',
  ....
  valueN:'valueN'
})
```

but in your case it's look you want to save data objects in your state (list with associative), so it's a array that contains objects 
better to separate the value accord to object, and make the operations before with the array of objects before .setState

example:

```
const myNewCountryValues = [
  "USA" => { id: 1, name: "United States"},
  "FR"  => { id: 2, name: "France"},
]
```

then you can manage in a clean way the array:

```
newCountry = { id: 3, name: "Germany"} ;


myNewCountryValues.push ( newCountry );
```

with associative.key:

```
myNewCountryValues["GE"] = newCountry ;
```

update the state:

```
this.setState({ countries: myNewCountryValues});
```

or in one line:

```
this.setState({ countries: [...myNewCountryValues, newCountry]});
```